# Storing user data as JSON in Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nosql

I'm working on a sports app that allows users to edit roughly 500 rows of player stats at a time. Its similar to an editable spreadsheet with 500 rows and each user can potentially save multiple 'sheets'. I'm thinking this would put a lot of strain on the app.

I come from a LAMP background and am a little new to Rails. In a LAMP environment I would setup a hybrid system where I have a relational DB (Mysql) to store my general tables (user's email/pass, players, teams, etc) and in another table have the user_id and a path to a json file on the server with that users custom stats. This way when a user is editing a particular sheet I would just load and edit that one file.

Am I thinking about this the right way? I don't have much experience with NoSQL and I would prefer to not have the complexities of two databases. Is there some hybrid best practice in Rails to store a file path or serialize JSON as a field in Rails with a friendly way to manipulate it with AR?

I'm running Rails 4 and MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it sounds like you already have two databases: MySQL and the JSON file one you invented.

You could just as easily JSON/binary/gzip (or however) encode the data and save it in a [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) field in your MySQL database.

```
$ rake g migration add_player_data_to_users player_data:binary
$ rake db:migrate
```

In your User model

```
class User

  def player_data
    return nil unless @player_data.present?
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(@player_data))
  end

  def player_data= data
    @player_data = ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(data))
  end

end
```

With MySQL, you might have to edit the migration file and set the [:limit modifier](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-type-modifiers) to a accommodate the size of the resulting data

Comment: I haven't implemented anything yet, that was my first instinct. I'm just wondering if this is the most efficient way to go about doing it.

Comment: Sincerely no offense to you, but I don't think your JSON file database would be considered the most efficient. If you don't want to store binary data in your MySQL, you might want to consider MongoDB.

Comment: Would recommend something like MongoDB, sticking to MySQL, or both then?

Comment: There'd be no need for both. MongoDB would mean adding another dependency (and its dependencies) to your app; that, and it's additional complexities might outweigh its benefits if you only plan on using it for one thing. Most importantly, don't pre-optimize. I'd try to get it working with your existing MySQL database. If it doesn't perform to your requirements, consider an alternative.

Comment: I like the "don't pre-optimize" suggestion, always good advice for any project. I just wanted to make sure I was on the right track before I went any further.